# What to do when vscode rg.exe is blocked

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode in portable mode and for some reason rg.exe is being blocked from running by another program. I don't have admin privileges on the computer to unblock it. As a result, some features have stopped working like (git) extensions, settings, and file search.

vscode version: 1.65.2

```
file path: ...resources\app\node_modules.asar.unpacked\@vscode\ripgrep\bin\rg.exe
```

Is there any workaround to make rg.exe work or any alternative to use?

Comment: i have the same issue and have posted the images and issues here with a few more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77410328/vscode-fails-to-install-because-of-rg-exe