# vscode fails to install because of rg.exe

Tags: visual-studio-code

I get this error message. Its has happened quite a few times and is becoming an annoyance.

[image]

Next i get this:

[image]

Things i have tried.

- close all instance of vscode.
- close all applications.
- task manager to end the `rg.exe` task (doesn't work).

On google search it seems like this is linked to npm (but i dont know how). I rarely use node (mostly python).

the only option left is to restart the PC...

the actual full path of the offending file is here:

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar.unpacked\@vscode\ripgrep\bin\rg.exe
```

i have tried to kill the process in the command prompt (as admin) like this:

```
taskkill /im rg.exe /f /t
```

but it still persists.

How can i prevent this from occurring ?

Comment: what exactly do you observe when you try to end `rg.exe` in the task manager? I.e. what exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Task Manager says you can't? (then give an exact error message) It gets killed but immediately comes back?

Comment: have you tried using `taskkill`? Ex. `taskkill //F //FI "IMAGENAME eq rg.exe" //T`

Comment: no, but i would not expect to have to **kill the task** each time i restart the application. This is an issue with VScode (or one of its applications) in some way...

Comment: there's a dotnet runtime extension that another extension I use depends upon. I've gotten used to it persisting in the background and having to kill it to update my VS Code.

Comment: @starball,  i am unable to kill the task. it persists.  what do you do to kill it ?   which is the guilty extension please? - i can try to remove it.

Comment: If you can't kill it from task manager or by using the command I gave above, then I can't help you. ripgrep is bundled with VS Code for its builtin search-across-files feature.